# Dúvida com textbox

Tags: c#, log, textbox

Estou tentando criar uma tela de `log` utilizando uma `textbox` em `C#`.

Em determinados pontos do programa, eu gostaria de inserir uma linha nessa `textbox`. Confiram o exemplo:

```
Linha 1> Realizando inserção..
Linha 2> Dados inseridos..
Linha 3> Pedido Realizado.
```

Tentei fazer isso assim:

```
txtBoxLog.Text = "Realizando inserção..\n";
```

Mas a cada linha dessa o programa, ao invés de inserir uma nova linha na `textbox`, ele apaga o que está escrito e coloca o novo valor.

Atenciosamente,
Yves Fernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TextBox` está configurada como `Multiline`? se sim basta fazer isso;

```
txtBoxLog.Text += "Realizando inserção..\n";
```

O comando de atribuição `+=` concatena o conteúdo atual com o conteúdo prévio.

Comment: Acho que a sua "pergunta" já responderia o problema, que aparentemente é o multiline desativado mesmo.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Mesmo se o multiline tivesse ativado, ele está apagando o valor anterior e setando um novo usando `Text = ""`, o certo é usar do jeito que está na resposta.

Comment: Felipe, Bom dia. Obrigado pela resposta, ela respondeu minha pergunta.
Vou marcar como respondida.

Minha textbox está como multiline e só com o \n pularia de linha?

Comment: Sim ele adicionaria uma quebra de linha mas como você estava usando o = somente ele substituía o conteúdo anterior.

Comment: Show!. Muito Obrigado a todos.